# Determine if substring corresponds to specific code (character types) in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, character

I have a collection of strings and want to filter out those where the last four characters are: (alpha)(alpha)(number)(number).

I know I can make a substring of each of these and separately, but what is the method to determine the types of the characters in the sequence?

This is for SQL in Hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.  Something like:

```
where col regexp '[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}$'
```